# Password protect Apple ID settings on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Can a password be set for preventing the access to this screen once iPhone is unlocked?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) There's no way to do so in iOS. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't set a password, but **you can prevent access to the Apple ID settings screen** with Screen Time:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Open Screen Time.
3. Open Content & Privacy Restrictions.
4. Open Account Changes, select "Don't Allow" and tap "Back":
   [image]

   Now the Apple ID link in Settings should be grayed out and unselectable.

I'd recommend that you set a passcode with the option "Use Screen Time Passcode" in Setings > Screen Time to prevent others from changing back the setting.

If you wish to access the Apple ID screen, go through the steps above but select "Allow" instead.